# ASP.Net MVC Microsoft Integrated User Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net Mvc automatically generate User Database when you create internet project. I want the tables from this database to be created automatically again but on my database. How can be done this ?

I think this database is automatically created on

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I want to be created on my connection string. So I can be able to see the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") //<--- change it to your connectionstringname
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

change DefaultConnetion to the connection string name that you want these tables to be created.

Comment: So if I change the connection string. These tables will be created automatically ?

Comment: yes you can change the connection string too.EF code first will automatically generate the tables. if not then use migration to generate the tables.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx